# How to put a local .jpg file into a HTML document

Tags: html

I am in the beginning stages of building a website and have tried to put a picture that is on my computer into a HTML document that I've been working on in VS code. When I open the HTML document in a browser everything is there except for the image.

Methods tried:
1.
2. renamed the file then tried

I havent specified the width or height yet because im waiting to see the actual image

Comment: Post your HTML code. And the path to your image in order for people to help you.

Comment: For some reason it didnt post

Comment: <img src="soap image.jpg" alt="box of soap" /> first method i tried

Comment: <img src="C:\Users\16183\OneDrive\Pictures\soap image 1"/> second method tried

Comment: both the HTML file and the image that im trying to put into the file are in the same folder also

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<img src="path-to-img.jpg">`, image and your html file should be in same directory.

Comment: The image can be in another directory. It doesn't have to be in the same.

Comment: Zakk, I'm talking about my case